# Using two USART ports on the STM32-Discovery

Tags: multithreading, interrupt, stm32f4discovery

I am using an STM32-Discovery board for my first time. I want to use two of the USART ports on the board at the same time to read in serial information. Can the STM32 read in serial information from both of these USART ports at the same time? Do I need to set an interrupt instead, to switch between them?
I realize this is connected to threading on the board, but I do not understand the threading of the board.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write as many peripherals as you wish. But of course you need to do it a proper way. For example if you poll for the data from UART1 the data can be overrun on the another ones. So you need to implement other methods like using the interrupts. The topic is too broad for the simple answer.